# change highchart data using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have made a chart on my website using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), and it's working sucessfully.

Now I have added a radio button on my chart and want it to change the data when I select a radio button list.

Here is my working chart:

```
   $(function() {

       $('#container1').highcharts({
           chart: {
               type: 'column'
           },

          title: {
           text: 'Information '
           },
            yAxis: {
               title: {
               text: 'data'
        } },


      series: [{

               name: '2011-2012',
               color: '#0000FF',
               data: [1, 0, 4]
     },  {   
              color: '#FF0000',
              name: '2013-2014',
              data: [5, 4, 8]
   }]
       });

   });

</script>
```

This is the radio button I have added:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radioList" ID="RadioButtonList1"
                AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">data</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">data2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">data3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How can i select radio button data3, and then show a new set of data?
The closest I came was:

```
$("#change").click(function(){
if ($("#list").val() == "A")
{
options.series = [{name: 'A', data: [1,2,1]}]
 }
 else
 {
options.series = [{name: 'B', data: [3,2,3]}]
 } 
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);    
 });
```

This does not work, why?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to feed chart with a new series, use one of:

- [series.setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29) function to update series with new data
- remove all series series using [series.remove](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove%28%29) and then add new series using [chart.addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29)

Comment: Paewel, do you no how do i add extra stuff such as yaxis title, because at the moment they all the same for a,b and c.

Comment: The same way like `setData` use `yAxis[0].update( { title: 'new name' });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-calculate the chart. Take a look in their API for the refresh method.
You don't need to create a new instance.
**EDIT:** [Here you go!](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw%28%29)

**EDIT2:**
Assuming you have a `<select>` with ID `list`:

```
$('#list').on('change', function(e){
  if ($(this).val() == 0) {
    chart.series = [{name: 'A', data: [1,2,1]}]
  } else if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    // And so on..
  }
  // Update the chart now that we have modified the series
  chart.redraw();
});
```

Comment: I just wrote that out of my mind. The method is called `redraw`, and you can find it on the link I provided :-)

Comment: yeah i had a look at it, problem is, mine is using radio buttons, and the example is using buttons, its changing it that's the problem. that example prints data, i need data to show using the radio button.

Comment: thats not working iv added it on and its giving me an error, "uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token( $('#list').on('change', function(e){
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
  if ($(this).val() == 0) {
    chart.series = [{name: